# How to check presense of verb using spacy and pandas?

Tags: regex, pandas, nltk, spacy

```
import spacy, en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
doc = nlp(u"I will go to the mall")
chk_set = set(['VERB'])
print chk_set.issubset(t.pos_ for t in doc)
```

The code above returns **True** `if POS = verb` is present.

Now I want to extend this code to read through a list of sentences stored in an excel sheet. To check the presence of punctuation in the sentence I am able to achieve it using the code below.

The question is how to extend this the code below to incorporate verb check above.

```
from pandas import read_excel
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
my_sheet_name = 'Metrics' 
df = read_excel('sentence.xlsx', sheet_name = my_sheet_name)
df['.']=df['Sentence'].str.contains('.')
# df['VERB']=df['Sentence'].str.contains('.')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('sentence.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Metrics')
writer.save()
```

Expected result:

```
Sentence                            Verb
I will go to the mall               True
the mall                            False
I may be here tomorrow.             True
```

Comment: More importantly, i want to know how to pass data frames into nlp.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using `NLTK` as below:

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'sent': ['I will go to the mall', 'the mall', 'I may be here tomorrow.']})

def tag_verb(sent):
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
    tags = nltk.pos_tag(words)
    for t in tags:
        if t[1] == 'VB':
            return True
    return False

df['verb'] = df['sent'].apply(lambda x: tag_verb(x))
```

Output:

```
    sent                       verb
0   I will go to the mall      True
1   the mall                   False
2   I may be here tomorrow.    True
```

Comment: How do you do use read_excel in your example to read from xlsx file containing column name as sent

Comment: Your concern was regarding POS tagging, so I provided solution by creating a dummy data. If you are having trouble with reading the data, I think you should search similar question on SO or ask a new question.